# Apache Airflow Dev 2.0 setup on Windows 10

Tags: docker, airflow

I am very new to Apache Airflow, can someone please provide the steps to install and run Apache Airflow Dev 2.0 on windows environment (including Docker); where as I found lot of good articles on installing Apache Airflow 1.10.x...

Answer (score 1):

I've been playing with Airflow 2.0 (using official Docker image apache/airflow:master) with the Celery Executor locally myself on Windows 10 using Docker (WSL2).

Note, that in Airflow 2.0 you have to make use of the RBAC UI, which means after you initialise the DB, you'll have to create a user for yourself which you can do via the airflow CLI, when you hop into the container:

```
airflow users create -r Admin -u admin -e admin@example.com -f admin -l user -p admin
```

Here is the docker-compose.yml file I am using - or [check out the complete example on my GitHub](https://github.com/zahiar/apache-airflow-playground/tree/master/example-docker-compose-celery-airflow-2.0):

```
version: "3.7"

x-apache-airflow-base: &apache-airflow-base
  image: apache/airflow:master
  environment:
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres:5432/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres:5432/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: FB0o_zt4e3Ziq3LdUUO7F2Z95cvFFx16hU8jTeR1ASM=
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: "True"
  volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
  depends_on:
    - postgres
    - redis

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:11.5
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata

  redis:
    image: redis:5
    environment:
      REDIS_HOST: redis
      REDIS_PORT: 6379

  webserver:
    <<: *apache-airflow-base
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

  flower:
    <<: *apache-airflow-base
    command: celery flower
    ports:
      - 5555:5555

  scheduler:
    <<: *apache-airflow-base
    command: scheduler

  worker:
    <<: *apache-airflow-base
    command: celery worker
```